# Trying to reduce an array of objects to a similar but summed up array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

So I have an array of objects that looks like:

```
dataArray = [
    {Revenue: 5, Date: "2018-06-05T00:00:00", DateString: "6/5/2018"},
    {Revenue: 10, Date: "2018-06-05T00:00:00", DateString: "6/5/2018"},
    {Revenue: 5, Date: "2018-06-05T00:00:00", DateString: "6/5/2018"},
    {Revenue: 1, Date: "2018-06-13T00:00:00", DateString: "6/13/2018"},
    {Revenue: 4, Date: "2018-06-13T00:00:00", DateString: "6/13/2018"}
]
```

And what I need is to reduce that down to another array of objects that looks like:

```
reducedDataArray = [
    {Revenue: 20, Date: "2018-06-05T00:00:00", DateString: "6/5/2018"},
    {Revenue: 5, Date: "2018-06-13T00:00:00", DateString: "6/13/2018"}
]
```

Basically if the date is the same then the revenue needs to be summed up so that there aren't multiple instances of the same date. Unfortunately I am limited to our version of Typescript so I don't have all the cool ES6 goodies to help with this stuff. I've tried using things like reduce() but I think a combination of not knowing what the heck I'm doing and this being kind of weird has left me in a fog.

Any suggestions or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add the code you've tried to your question.

Comment: you don't need anything fancy to loop through and add totals by key (date) to a blank object, which you can then turn back into an array, deriving datestring from date; ES3 is plenty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Played with some loops and it works

```
dataArray = [
    {Revenue: 5, Date: "2018-06-05T00:00:00", DateString: "6/5/2018"},
    {Revenue: 10, Date: "2018-06-05T00:00:00", DateString: "6/5/2018"},
    {Revenue: 5, Date: "2018-06-05T00:00:00", DateString: "6/5/2018"},
    {Revenue: 1, Date: "2018-06-13T00:00:00", DateString: "6/13/2018"},
    {Revenue: 4, Date: "2018-06-13T00:00:00", DateString: "6/13/2018"}
];

const getUnique=array=>{
  return array.filter((value, index, self)=> { 
      return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  });
}

let date=[];
let output=[];

for(const v of dataArray) date.push(v.Date);
for(const v of getUnique(date)){

  let revenue=0,date=v,dateString;
  for(const x of dataArray){
    if(x.Date==v) revenue+=x.Revenue;
    dateString=x.DateString;
  }

  output.push({
    Revenue:revenue,
    Date:v,
    DateString:dateString
  });

}

console.log(output);
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nbz6ra12/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm marking this as the answer because it follows a similar pattern to other code I'm working with.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reduce` to create an object with date keys and then convert the object back to an array.

```
let dataArray = [
    {Revenue: 5, Date: "2018-06-05T00:00:00", DateString: "6/5/2018"},
    {Revenue: 10, Date: "2018-06-05T00:00:00", DateString: "6/5/2018"},
    {Revenue: 5, Date: "2018-06-05T00:00:00", DateString: "6/5/2018"},
    {Revenue: 1, Date: "2018-06-13T00:00:00", DateString: "6/13/2018"},
    {Revenue: 4, Date: "2018-06-13T00:00:00", DateString: "6/13/2018"}
]
// We need to specify the type parameter explicitly, as it will not be inffered from initial value 
let valuesObj = dataArray.reduce<{ [date: string]: typeof dataArray[number] }>((p, v) => {
    const existing = p[v.Date];
    if (existing) {
        existing.Revenue += v.Revenue
    } else {
        p[v.Date] = Object.assign({}, v); //Create a copy so as to not change the original when we sum 
    }
    return p;
}, {});


// You can use Object.values(valuesObj) if available 
let values = Object.keys(valuesObj).map(k => valuesaObj[k]);
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20dataArray%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20Revenue%3A%205%2C%20Date%3A%20"2018-06-05T00%3A00%3A00"%2C%20DateString%3A%20"6%2F5%2F2018"%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20Revenue%3A%2010%2C%20Date%3A%20"2018-06-05T00%3A00%3A00"%2C%20DateString%3A%20"6%2F5%2F2018"%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20Revenue%3A%205%2C%20Date%3A%20"2018-06-05T00%3A00%3A00"%2C%20DateString%3A%20"6%2F5%2F2018"%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20Revenue%3A%201%2C%20Date%3A%20"2018-06-13T00%3A00%3A00"%2C%20DateString%3A%20"6%2F13%2F2018"%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20Revenue%3A%204%2C%20Date%3A%20"2018-06-13T00%3A00%3A00"%2C%20DateString%3A%20"6%2F13%2F2018"%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20valuesaObj%20%3D%20dataArray.reduce<%7B%20%5Bdate%3A%20string%5D%3A%20typeof%20dataArray%5Bnumber%5D%20%7D>((p%2C%20v)%20%3D>%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20existing%20%3D%20p%5Bv.Date%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(existing)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20existing.Revenue%20%2B%3D%20v.Revenue%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20p%5Bv.Date%5D%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20v)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20p%3B%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20values%20%3D%20Object.keys(valuesaObj).map(k%20%3D>%20valuesaObj%5Bk%5D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.write(JSON.stringify(values))%3B)

Comment: @prail and from my phone too :-P

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this out. I really appreciate it.